# Include Duplicates Order Numbers but Exclude Duplicate Prices

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table with all order numbers and shipments for a specific client. Sometimes there are multiple shipments on one order so, in order to include all shipments and orders there will be duplicate orders with different shipments. Is there a way to include the duplicate order number but only have the amount for each unique order show up once?
For example:

| Shop | Shipment | Order# | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | a | 1 | 5 |
| x | b | 1 | - |
| x | c | 1 | - |
| x | d | 2 | 8 |
| x | e | 2 | - |

Comment: ... but seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by order# order by shipment)
             then sum(amount) over (partition by order#)
        end) as order_amount
from t
order by order#, shipment;
```